# Visual Studio Custom Color

Tags: vb.net

So I'm wondering if there is a way where I can have a custom color background Using the **RGB**. I have the three text boxes one for Red one for Green and One for the Blue.
But when i try this code for it

```
Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text)
```

It just won't work... I Tried searching it up on Google and no results found for what I want it to do

Comment: What is the `type` for the parameters for the `.FromArgb`?

Comment: What means "wont't work"? what are exactly the values that you are passing? and when are you using that order?. The questions lacks of details.

Comment: @OneFineDay Like the size of the Form?

Comment: @ElektroStudios, it does matter. There is no protection from entering a string instead of just numbers and `Option Strict On` does not compile.

Comment: @ElektroStudios It comes up with two errors for that line... one saying ')' Expected. And the other one saying Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'Color'. I don't know why it is unable to work

Comment: @OneFineDay It does not matter since the OP didn't specified any exception, then we can assume he has not enabled `Option Strict` and he is passing proper values that are casted by the compiler, without throwing an exception.

Comment: @ElektroStudios I have not enabled it...

Comment: what are exactlly the values that you've put in those textboxes? you should use values between 0-255

Comment: @ElektroStudios None At the moment.. Because I want it to use for RGB. that reaches to a max number of 255 on all three

Comment: @ElektroStudios It is unable to detect the text boxes though

Comment: RGB = Red:0-255, Green:0-255 and Blue:0-255 plus alpha channel:0-255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to avoid textboxes then better use a `NumericUpDown` control in order to friendly set a maximum value of **255**, then suscribe to the `ValueChanged` or `KeyUp` event depending on the responsiveness behavior you want.

An example:

[image]

```
Public Class Form1 : Inherits Form

    Private Sub NumericUpDownRGB_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) _
    Handles NumericUpDownR.ValueChanged,
            NumericUpDownG.ValueChanged,
            NumericUpDownB.ValueChanged

        Dim r As Integer = CInt(Me.NumericUpDownR.Value)
        Dim g As Integer = CInt(Me.NumericUpDownG.Value)
        Dim b As Integer = CInt(Me.NumericUpDownB.Value)

        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Me.BackColor.A, r, g, b)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would say is to make sure that you enable [`Option Strict`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) it will tell the compiler to notify you of implicit type conversions among other things.

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type

Since you are using a TextBox for input I would use the [`Integer.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) Method to make sure that you are entering the proper data, something like this.

```
Private Sub SetBackground()
    Dim argR, argG, argB As Byte
        If Byte.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, argR) Then
            If Byte.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, argG) Then
                If Byte.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, argB) Then
                    Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(argR, argG, argB)
                    Return
                End If
            End If
        End If
        MsgBox("Error Invalid Entry", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Entry Error")
End Sub
```